# How to align <label> on the same line with other element

Tags: css

How can I get `<label>` and `#slider` to be on the same line?

```css
header {
  background: #2f2f2f;
  width: 600px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}

header a {
  color: #FFF;
}

header a:hover,
header a:focus {
  color: #DDD;
}

header #title {
  padding: 7px 0;
  float: left;
}

header #onoff {
  padding: 6px 0;
  float: right;
  height: 16px;
}

header #onoff label#switch input {
  display: none;
}

header #onoff label#switch input+#slider {
  background: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

header #onoff label#switch input+#slider:before {
  content: "";
  background: #FFF;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header #onoff label#switch input:checked+#slider {
  background: #4CD964;
}

header #onoff label#switch input:checked+#slider:before {
  transform: translateX(11px);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a id="title" href=".">Site title</a>
  <span id="onoff"><label id="switch">NIGHT MODE<input id="toggle" type="checkbox"><span id="slider"></span></label>
  </span>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly discourage you to use floats for this. Use a flexbox instead:

```css
header {
  background: #2f2f2f;
  width: 600px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header a {
  color: #FFF;
}

header a:hover,
header a:focus {
  color: #DDD;
}

header #title {
  padding: 7px 0;
}

header #onoff {
  padding: 6px 0;
  height: 16px;
}

header #onoff label#switch input {
  display: none;
}

header #onoff label#switch input+#slider {
  background: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

header #onoff label#switch input+#slider:before {
  content: "";
  background: #FFF;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header #onoff label#switch input:checked+#slider {
  background: #4CD964;
}

header #onoff label#switch input:checked+#slider:before {
  transform: translateX(11px);
}

#switch {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a id="title" href=".">Site title</a>
  <span id="onoff"><label id="switch">NIGHT MODE<input id="toggle" type="checkbox"><span id="slider"></span></label>
  </span>
</header>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with floats... it is just because of the '#slider' element being within that label element...

Comment: Which isn't a problem if you would be using flexbox. Your original approach is **very, very outdated**, ask any developer with basic knowledge! Floats should only (and I mean **only**) be used to make text float around other objects, such as images. [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+you+shouldn%27t+be+using+floats)!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want.

```css
header {
   background: #2f2f2f;
   width: 600px;
   height: 28px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 10px;
   color: #FFF;
   font-size: 12px;
}

header a {
   color: #FFF;
}

header a:hover,
header a:focus {
   color: #DDD;
}

header #title {
   padding: 7px 0;
   float: left;
}

header #onoff {

   padding: 6px 0;
   float: right;
   height: 16px;
}

header #onoff label#switch input {
   display: none;
}

header #onoff label#switch input+#slider {

   background: #CCC;
   /* display: inline-block; */
   width: 27px;
   height: 16px;
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: .4s;
   border-radius: 34px;
}

header #onoff label#switch input+#slider:before {
   content: "";
   background: #FFF;
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   position: absolute;
   transition: .4s;
   border-radius: 50%;
}

header #onoff label#switch input:checked+#slider {
   background: #4CD964;
}

header #onoff label#switch input:checked+#slider:before {
   transform: translateX(11px);
}

#switch {
   display: flex;
   width: 120px;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-around;
   line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a id="title" href=".">Site title</a>
  <span id="onoff">
     <label id="switch">NIGHT MODE<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
        <span id="slider"></span>
     </label>
  </span>
</header>
```